# domain, boundary point, and limit of f(x,y)

Tags: limits

Let $f(x,y)$ be defined by

$f(x,y) = (x^2y^2)/(x^2y^2 + (x-y)^2)$
a) Find the domain of the function $f$.

b) show that $(0,0)$ is a boundary point of the domain of $f$

c) Compute the following limit if it exists:
$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)$

So far, I have a) as being $x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 < 2xy$. Is this correct? Or is the domain simply all points where $x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2$ does not equal $2xy$

for b) I kind of have to be sure of what my domain is. So I can't give an answer to this yet.

c) I don't like limits. I believe that this limit exists and is equal to zero. But I don't know how to prove that. It's easier to prove a limit if it doesn't exist because all you need to do is find a path that doesn't work. But they all seem to work for me here.

Please help. I asked someone to help me earlier and they tried to nudge me in the right direction but I just can't seem to get this.

Answer (score 1):

a) The domain of this function is all values such that the denominator is not equal to 0. Then we must simply find the solution to $x^2y^2+(x-y)^2=0$ and this will be all points such that this is not true. But notice $xy=0$ if and only if $x=0$ or $y=0$ for the real numbers. Then $x=0$ and $y=0$ is a solution. Now if we observe all values $(x-y)^2$ and $x^2y^2$ as positive for all nonzero $x$ and $y$, then we need only consider this point $(0,0)$. Therefore the domain of $f=\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0)\}$.

b) Let $N_{(0,0)}((0,0), \varepsilon)$ be a neighborhood around $(0,0)$ with radius $\varepsilon>0$. Then we have $\frac{\varepsilon-0}{2}$ is in $N_{(0,0)}((0,0), \varepsilon)$. However, $(0,0)$ is not in this set. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have that all neighborhoods of $(0,0)$ contain points of the domain and points not in the domain. Therefore $(0,0)$ is a boundary point.

c) Fix $x=0$. Then we may see that $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0} f(0,y) = 0$. Similarly if we fix $y=0$ we see $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x,0) = 0$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! part a) I fully understand. part b) I mostly get, but why is it that (0,0) is not contained in the set if the neighborhood is centered around that point? And for part c) I've tried many possible paths an they all lead to zero. But that isn't enough to definitively say that the limit exists, and I'm not sure how to do that. We used the triangle inequality once in class to prove it, but it doesn't really apply here I don't think.

Comment: @infinitylord Sorry, $(0,0)$ IS in the neighborhood. It is not in the set $\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0)\}$ by definition though. To prove the limit exists you may need to do an $\varepsilon$ argument showing that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(f(x,y),(0,0))<\varepsilon$ $\forall \varepsilon>0$ and $\forall n>N$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss part (a).  Unless stated otherwise, the domain of the function is the set of points where the function is defined.  This function is defined everywhere the denominator is not equal to 0.  Call is set of points $S$.  So the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2 - S$.